# AngularJs - What exactly does $route.current contain?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

According to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route), `$route.current` contains `controller` and `locals`.

For example, if this is one of my route:

```
    $routeProvider
    .when('/item1/:value', {
        templateUrl: 'item1.html',
        controller: 'Item1Controller',
        title: 'Item 1'
    });
```

`{{$route.current}}` prints out `{"params":{"value":"value1"},"pathParams":{"value":"value1"},"loadedTemplateUrl":"item1.html","locals":{"$template":"<p>item 1:{{params}}</p>","$scope":"$SCOPE"},"scope":"$SCOPE"}`

1. Why isn't there `controller`?
2. `{{$route.current.title}}` prints out "Item 1." But above there isn't property `title`?

What exactly does `$route.current` contain?

Comment: How and where are you *"printing it out"*? FYI, `JSON.stringify()` does not print out function properties

Comment: Like the example in the docs, assign `$route` to the `$rootScope` and then in the html just use `{{$route.current}}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`$route.current`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#current) object has several documented properties, and `controller` is one of them. All properties that were defined in route definition object with `when` method are available in `$route.current`, because the latter [prototypically inherits from a copy of the former](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.5/src/ngRoute/route.js#L657):

```
$route.current.hasOwnProperty('controller') === false;

Object.getPrototypeOf($route.current).hasOwnProperty('controller') === true;

'controller' in $route.current === true;
```

The properties that are stored in `$route.current` object prototype aren't serialized when the object is converted to string. Angular interpolation shouldn't be used as a trusted way to get valuable tracing output, always use `console` instead.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. The example in the docs also prints out `{{$route.current.params}}` and `{{$route.current.scope.name}}`. Well, why are these two properties `params` and `scope` not documented? I'm new to AngularJs, and I really hope the documentation is complete.

Comment: @Shawn params isn't documented because the suggested way to retrieve it is `$routeParams`. And there's hardly a single good use for `$route.current.scope`. You are free to use whatever you will find there, e.g. `$route.current.originalPath` is undocumented but a useful one.